# Getting user coordinates for setting MapView in my app generates undefined values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am developing an app where a user navigates to a map view. On entering the MapView, I want the app to set the initialRegion to the longitude & latitudes coordinates of the user.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
export default function MapScreen() {
  const [longitude, setLong] = React.useState();
  const [latitude, setLat] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLong(position.coords.longitude),
        setLat(position.coords.latitude)
      })
  });
  return (
      <MapView style={styles.map} initialRegion={{
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 1,
        longitudeDelta: 1
      }} />
    );
}
```

Unfortunately this generates an error `The prop initialRegion.latitude is marked as required in MapView but its value is undefined` .. Same for the initialRegion.longitude. Can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 0):

## Don't load the map if there's no coordinates set

You should wait for the lat and long to be set.

In the version below you map will not be loaded until the lat and long have values. You should set up a loading state whilst you're awaiting the values for lat and long.

I don't think you need use effect either.

```
export default function MapScreen() {
  const [longitude, setLong] = React.useState();
  const [latitude, setLat] = React.useState();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   (position) => {
    setLong(position.coords.longitude),
    setLat(position.coords.latitude)
   }
  )
  return (latitude && longitude) ? (
      <MapView style={styles.map} initialRegion={{
        latitude,
        longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 1,
        longitudeDelta: 1
      }} />
    ) : null;
}
```

Comment: that means latitude and longitude are never populated, can you `console.log({latitude, longitude})` before the return?

Comment: That was my main issue .. So what is causing it ?

Comment: did you get permission for the location?
click the lock on top left and look at `site settings`.

Comment: what lock please ? Where is it found ?

Comment: remove `UseEffect` you only need to check lat and long once at the start right. Edited answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196814/discussion-between-joe-lloyd-and-carl).